# Not getting proper character encoding with Facebook posts data

Tags: python, mysql, facebook-graph-api, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to populate Facebook posts data from a particular page (here bestbuy), extracted via Graph API (https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk), to mysql tables. I'm extracting posts as well as comments to posts. Here I'm talking about comments, same issue is applicable to posts. Character set is set as utf-8 for the db schema.
Now when I insert the comment content (comment_message) in the database I do `comment_message.encode('utf-8')` in Python script before inserting. But it doesn't work properly and a lot of characters are replaced with some other characters. So for the comment in the following post -
https://www.facebook.com/12699262021/posts/10152351243512022

results in the following after `comment_message.encode('utf-8')` -

> Hola ├æon-
>
> Muchas gracias por tu pregunta. En caso de que no hayas tenido el
>   momento, te re comiendo visitar nuestra p├ígina online
>   http://BestBuy.com.
>
> Aqu├¡ encontraras los precios sin impuestos. Lo impuestos var├¡an
>   dependiendo la  cuidad y la tienda en donde finalices la compra.
>
> Ten en cuenta que todos los productos que compres con Best Buy est├ín
>   destinados  al uso de los Estados Unidos, cada producto tiene una
>   garant├¡a de fabricante e n forma gratuita. Para saber m├ís detalles
>   de la garant├¡a del fabricante, te ac onsejamos que te comuniques con
>   Nikon.
>
> Hasta mi mejor conocimiento, todas nuestras tiendas localizadas en
>   Nueva York es tar├ín abiertas  el 18 de abril.
>
> Atentamente, Karina

You can see a lots of characters are messed up. Below is the table schema in which I'm inserting using `pymysql` -

```
CREATE TABLE `xxxxxxxxxxxxxx` (
  `comment_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT '-',
  `from_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT '-',
  `from_category` varchar(50) DEFAULT '-',
  `from_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT '-',
  `message` varchar(10000) DEFAULT '-',
  `created_time` varchar(45) DEFAULT '-',
  `likes` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `page` varchar(50) DEFAULT '-',
  `type` varchar(100) DEFAULT '-',
  `inserted_time` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

If I try to insert the content directly without any encoding, I get -

```
    sql = sql.encode(self.encoding)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 148-149:
 ordinal not in range(256)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue here. I need to do following two things to get rid of it -

First, setting default character set to Unicode in Python script -

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Second, while connecting to db, set the parameters `use_unicode` and `charset` -

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='xx', user='xx', passwd='xx', db='xx', use_unicode=True, charset='utf8')
```